# Appending Value to NSMutableArray and Saving to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am creating a names generator app for iPhone and this is what I am trying to do.

- Allow the user to save the current generated name by clicking a save button.

In order to do this, here is what is happening:

- The current babyname is displayed in a `UILabel`.
- The user presses 'save' and then the label.text value is appended to a `NSMutableArray` (I don't think this is working in my code correctly).
- The `NSMutableArray` is then saved in `NSUserDefaults`.
- The contents will then be loaded in another view to populate `UITableView` cells.

My specific question is, am I handling this saving/persistent storage process correctly? Here is the snippet in question:

```
- (IBAction)saveName:(id)sender {
// save current baby name to array
NSMutableArray *babyNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[babyNameArray addObject:babyname.text];

// save list of babynames to nsuserdefaults

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:babyNameArray forKey:@"My Key"];


// for testing log names listed in nsuserdefaults
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

}
```

Here is a link to the pastebin of the whole file contents (with comments): http://pastebin.com/hQRM9Azh

Comment: What results are you getting now?

Comment: The NSLog console shows the first name saved and the most recent name saved.. even when I save 3+ names.

Comment: You need to synchronize the nsuserdefaults to save to them! [NSUserDefaults synchronize]

Comment: Right, since you're creating a new mutable array, adding one object to it, and saving that.

Comment: OK, I added [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; just before the NSLog statement and it's still only showing 2 names on the log instead of 3,4 or 5 that I have "saved".

Comment: @noa I thought I was adding each successive "saved" name to the array?

Comment: But you are not appending the existing uservdeafults values to your array before saving it, so how do you want it to keep the old values?

Comment: @Lefteris OK - so I should alloc,init the array outside of the save method and then load it, addObject and save it within the method, right?

Comment: See noa's answer. It's correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you add, you're starting again with an empty array (`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`) – instead of starting with the existing items.

Here's some code which adds to the existing entries instead:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *babyNameArray = [[defaults stringArrayForKey:@"My Key"] mutableCopy];
if (!babyNameArray) babyNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[babyNameArray addObject:babyname.text];
[defaults setObject:babyNameArray forKey:@"My Key"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Thnx Buddy This exact example what i want.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things before we start addressing the big issue. First, you'll want to have those arrays of names stored somewhere in a file(s), which you'll read either when the application starts, or in `ViewWillAppear`/`ViewWillLoad`.

Second, the way you have things working right now, you will only save one name at a time. You alloc & init a new (empty) array every time the user clicks the "Save Name" button. You then add the current name to this (empty) array and set it as the object for key "My Key." Note that your "My Key" object will always have only one element - the most recently saved name.

And lastly, you never actually save your changes to `NSUserDefaults`. If I recall correctly, after you are done making changes to it, you need to call `synchronize` - otherwise your changes will be lost as soon as the application closes. Which kind of kills the whole purpose of using data persistance. :)

Comment: The first part doesn't make sense to me. NSUserDefaults takes care of persistence for you – that's the point of using it. Second and third parts sound good, though.

Comment: Thank you Argent for the comment - I'll put those first + middle name arrays in their own files and read from viewwillappear.